# pyinstaller exe work different from Python code

Tags: python, path, pyinstaller

my code work fine and in diffrenet methods but when I convert it to `.exe` it crash and return diffrent output
here is my full code :

```
import os 
import sys
from get_project_root import root_path
from pathlib import Path

# 1
root_1 = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
print(root_1)

#2
root_2 = os.path.dirname(sys.modules['__main__'].__file__)
print(root_2)

#3
root_3 = root_path(ignore_cwd=False)
print(root_3)

#4 
root_4 = Path(__file__).parent
print(root_4)
```

4 methods to get the root path for the project
if I run it with `py` it return the right output or it is what I want atless
somthing like that :

```
1: C:\Users\username\root\path
2: C:\Users\username\root\path
3: C:\Users\username\root\path
4: C:\Users\username\root\path
```

I compile with `pyinstaller --onefile main.py`
run the `.exe` and get this result :

```
1: C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI40362
2: C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI40362
3: C:\Users\Username\
4: C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI40362
```

so why `1,2,4` return this `Temp` path and not the project root ??
and the `3` return the path where terminal is running ??

this is my `.spec` file Maybe it will help :

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None

a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\Username\\Desktop\\test'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             hooksconfig={},
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,  
          [],
          name='main',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True,
          disable_windowed_traceback=False,
          target_arch=None,
          codesign_identity=None,
          entitlements_file=None )
```

I have 0 knowledge about pyinstaller maybe that's whay I can't fix this
so any ideas or solutions?

Comment: Did you had a look at the docs: https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/runtime-information.html

Comment: @MauriceMeyer   I check it right now and get the same result in `1,2,4`

Comment: So, whats the issue ? The project root is: `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI*` when bundled with pyInstaller.

Comment: @MauriceMeyer after some research I found that the code in link you send is working but I should remove `--onefile` after remove it is work fine like the original code 
Thank you 
now should I answer my own question ?
Or leave it as it is now ؟

Comment: You can answer the question yourself and accept it :)